# Link or button that sends a POST but does not navigate

Tags: html, button, hyperlink, target

I need an anchor tag or button that sends a POST to a URL but doesn't navigate to anywhere.

This might not comply with current standards, but it works in Chrome.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<iframe style="display:none;" name="some"></iframe>
<form method="POST" target="some">
<button class="btn" style="margin:0px 10px 15px 0px;" type="submit"
    formaction="http://www.example.org:1234/test?P1=X">Test</button>
</form>
```

Comment: You need to use Ajax.

Comment: Add method to your form. Example `<form id="myForm" method="POST">`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to post the data without navigating to another page or refreshing the same page, you need to use Ajax.

From your code, I assume you are using jQuery. In jQuery, there are functions that allow to implement Ajax easily.

I will add a sample code below for your reference.

```
$("#myLink").click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var url = "http://example.com"; //The url/uri where you want to post the data to
    var data = {field1: "data1", field2: "data2"}; //Your data
    $.post(url, data, function(data, status) {
        //Data and status from server after posting your data
        console.log(data);
        console.log(status);
    });
});
```

And your `a` tag will remain the same.

```
<a href="#" id="myLink">Send</a>
```

Comment: Thanks. So what would the <a> tag that calls this function look like?

Comment: @RichardU I have updated the answer with the `<a>` tag.

Comment: Thanks, Vivek. Unfortunately, that didn't work and I'm at a loss as to how to debug it. Plus, I really need to send the url and parameters to the function since I will have multiple instances. I have a spot in my theme for JavaScript Code and I have entered the function there. Maybe that's wrong.

Comment: Open the browser console and see if you get any errors? Also check the network tab in developer tools for any activity when you click the send button.

Comment: After spending all morning on this I realize I'm getting a mixed content error. The URL I need to hit is not HTTPS and I can't change it. A regular link works, but it takes me to a page that just says Done. I just want to replicate that without actually going to the new page. Ideas?